# How to use beforeInsert() and beforeUpdate() in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm working on an inventory management system in Grails, the application will keep track of assets information such as Users, Brand, Type etc.  I have 3 domain classes (other class are not important for this discussion) namely, **User**, **Movement** and **Inventory**.

Each assets is owned by a particular User.  When the asset is transferred from the current owner to a new owner in the Movement class, the change should be reflected in the User class and Inventory class.  These are my classes:

User:

```
class User {

    String userID
    String fullName
    String position
    Department department 

    String toString(){
        fullName
    }

    static hasMany = [inventories: Inventory, movementsByOldUser: Movement, movementsByNewUser: Movement]
    static mappedBy = [movementsByOldUser: 'oldUser', movementsByNewUser: 'newUser']

    static constraints = {
        userID blank: false, unique: true
        fullName blank: false
        position()
        department()

    }
}
```

Movement:

```
class Movement {

    User oldUser
    User newUser
    Inventory inventoryID
    Date movementDate
    User userResponsible

    static constraints = {
    inventoryID blank: false
    oldUser blank: false
    newUser blank: false
    movementDate()
    userResponsible blank: false
    }
}
```

Inventory:

```
class Inventory {

    String inventoryID
    String code
    String description
    String serial_num
    Date purchase_date
    Date record_date
    Type type 
    Brand brand 
    User user 


    static hasMany = [movements: Movement]

    String toString(){
        "$inventoryID, $type"
    }

    static constraints = {
        inventoryID blank: false, unique: true
        code blank: false
        description nullable: true, maxSize: 1000
        serial_num blank: false
        purchase_date()
        image nullable: true, maxSize: 1000000
        record_date()
        remarks nullable: true, maxSize: 1000
        type()
        brand()
        user()
    }
}
```

I have heard of the GORM method called beforeInsert() and beforeUpdate() that they can do the job, but I'm completely new to Grails, Groovy and of course GORM as this is the first application I develop, I have no idea how to use them in my codes. I did host of research but none match my scenario so I cannot get a clear picture of how to use it.

***Question edited from here:***
I have made some changes to the class User by using beforeUpdate() and beforeUpdate() but it gets an error shown below.

User class (edited version):

```
class User {

    String userID
    String fullName
    String position
    Department department 

    String toString(){
        fullName
    }

    static hasMany = [inventories: Inventory, movementsByOldUser: Movement, movementsByNewUser: Movement]
    static mappedBy = [movementsByOldUser: 'oldUser', movementsByNewUser: 'newUser']

    def beforeInsert(){
        this.fullName = 'oldUser'
    }

    def beforeUpdate(){
        this.fullName = 'newUser'
    }

    static constraints = {
        userID blank: false, unique: true
        fullName blank: false
        position()
        department()
    }
}
```

Error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000543e4bc2, pid=7488, tid=6520
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_05-b13) (build 1.8.0_05-b13)

# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.5-b02 mixed mode windows-amd64compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x424bc2]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Users\Kanaan\MFEDinventory\hs_err_pid7488.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# C:\Users\Kanaan\MFEDinventory\replay_pid7488.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Comment: There's a very clear explanation with examples in [the Grails user guide](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#eventsAutoTimestamping)

Comment: I have made some changes but then I encountered an error, did I do it right or wrong..??

Comment: What error do you get??

Comment: @Abdullah The error shown above, I do not know if it's related to User class or it's generated by something else.